# How to implement long lived network connection in dotnet

Tags: .net, wcf, networking

The idea is to have a windows service, that clients can connect to (tcp, wcf, remoting), and when the data changes in the windows service, send the changes to the clients. An example of this would be a stock pricing server, and when the price changes for instruments, send the changes to the client.

Wcf does have streaming, but is that just for streaming one big message response or can it be used for lots of small messages ?

Is sockets the only way to achieve this ?

Comment: I'm not sure keeping the connection open all the time is such a good idea... why not open/close the connection as you need it?  Or use multiple threads so you can have more then one connection open at the same time.

Comment: The server needs to handle multiple clients. There is going to be a continual stream of messages sent from server to clients, so doesn't make sense to open/close all the time.

Answer (score 1):

All connectivity, Wcf or otherwise, do use sockets in the backend.

You may want to customize "connection timeout" and "read timeout" for the connections made.